# Xamarin.Forms - Instantiate ViewModel Constructor everytime I open the page in AppShell

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm, constructor, page-refresh

I have a page that has some collection views that contains data. Data can be removed while using the app. The problem is that when I delete an object from that is part of one of these collection view (I delete it in another page), once I return to the page it still show me the object. I don't know if a RefreshView could be helpful since I'm updating data on the constructor. What should I do?

```
public MyViewModel() {
   Profile = App.currentUser;
   User additionalData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(Profile.AdditionalData);
   BorrowedBooks = additionalData.BorrowedBooks;
   Wishlist = additionalData.Wishlist; 
}
```

Comment: load your data in `OnAppearing` instead of in the constructor.  Alternately, you can use `MessagingCenter` to send a message whenever an item is removed

Comment: `The problem is that when I delete an object from that is part of one of these collection view (I delete it in another page)`  How do you delete an object from another page?  Could you please post more code snippets about this problem?

Comment: @Jason could you please write it as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load your data in `OnAppearing` instead of in the constructor. Alternately, you can use `MessagingCenter` to send a message whenever an item is removed